# Cannot use gem in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, soundcloud, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm a rails noob, so any help would be appreciated.

I've installed the soundcloud gem via:

```
$  gem install soundcloud
```

Then I added the gem to my Gemfile, and ran the rails bundle install to make sure it is included in my project:

```
$  bundle install
```

This output a list of all of the included gems for my project. One of the items towards the end was the soundcloud gem:

```
$  bundle install
...
Using sdoc 0.4.0
Using soundcloud 0.3.2
Using spring 1.1.2
...
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Now when I run the rails console in my application directory, I am able to access the soundcloud module as expected:

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.0)
2.1.1 :001 > SoundCloud
 => SoundCloud
2.1.1 :002 > client = SoundCloud.new(:client_id => 'b2dab282f8bb29467dcb4f5b27f7c075')
 => #<SoundCloud::Client:0x8972f40 ... (successful results here)
```

But when I try to use the soundcloud module in a controller or view, I get a page with the error:

```
uninitialized constant SlideshowController::SoundCloud
```

Here is the code where I try to use the soundcloud module:

```
helper_method :sc_get_src

def sc_get_src
    @sc_client ||= SoundCloud.new(:client_id => 'b2dab282f8bb29467dcb4f5b27f7c075')
    sound = @sc_client.get('/resolve', :url => @slideshow.sound)
    return sound.uri
end
```

On the documentation page [here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#resolving) the first line in the example is:

```
require 'soundcloud'
```

However, if I add that before I use the soundcloud module (in the controller, model, view etc) it throws this error:

```
cannot load such file -- soundcloud
```

Please help. Is there another step that I need to take to include the module in my application?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do I understand that you have the gem added to the gemfile?

Comment: Yes, I'll update the question to include this info.

Comment: Can you try running the console with -e production to see if the problem persist througout enviroments as stated in the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those problems are often solved by a restart of your rails server. E.g. For Passenger:

```
$ touch tmp/restart.txt
```

Reason is, that gem dependencies are only loaded in the startup phase of your app

Comment: One more comment to this topic. It is always a good hint that a restart is needed, when something works in the console but not in the webapp.